# Blender 2.83.2 - Only half of the icing's sprinkles are added to the icing

Tags: modeling

While following a tutorial by BlenderGuru, I ran into an issue where only half of the sprinkles were selected (as shown below).

[image: Donut top view]

I really don't know what could be causing this because I followed the tutorial step for step, and did exactly what the tutorial said.
If I make any change to the sprinkle object, like add a material, they all get effected, but if I do something like apply random colors to the sprinkles, only the selected half get effected. I have my model provided below if you need it.

The tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNmnPXY9UQA

My model:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem- I got the sprinkles part down but when I add the random colors, it seems like only half get affected (especially if we're adding more than 2 colors). I was trying to figure out the problem by remaking my sprinkle and messing around with the nodes... but it turns out nothing is wrong with it, it only looks like half is getting affected because we're looking at in through materials preview. If you go to rendered view, the sprinkle colors should be distributed more evenly according to your ColorRamp.